# How to make a jQuery slider loop

Tags: jquery, loops, slider

I have the following code for a slider and it works perfect but the slider stops after going throught the images to the last one. I want to make this slider loop infinitely. The code is:

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {

      setInterval("rotateImages()", 3000);
        });

    function rotateImages() {
        var oCurPhoto = $('#chica div.current');
        var oNxtPhoto = oCurPhoto.next();
        if (oNxtPhoto.lenght == 0)
            onNxtPhoto = $('#chica div.first');

        oCurPhoto.removeClass('current').addClass('previous');
        oNxtPhoto.css({opacity:0.0}).addClass('current').animate({opacity:1.0},2000,
        function() {
            oCurPhoto.removeClass('prevous');
            });
        $('#images').animate({"left": "=0"}, 1000);
       }
       </script>
```

The HTML is this:

```
      <div class="current">
     <a href="#"><img src="galeria_1.jpg" 
     alt="Galeria de Imagenes" width="960" height="310" class="galeria" /></a>
     </div>
     <div>
     <a href="#"><img src="galeria_1.jpg" alt="Galeria de Imagenes"               
     width="960" height="310" class="galeria" /></a>
     </div>
```

Here is the css:

```
   #chica div {
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 0;
  }

   #chica div.previous  {
   z-index: 1;
  }

   #chica div.current  {
   z-index: 2;
  }
```

If it helps here is the link to site "http://negociosensanjuan.com/w/Bufetes/"

What do I need to add to the jquery code to make it loop?

Comment: This is not a valid unit `"=0"`

Comment: Mind sharing some CSS? Also what is `#images` and what is `#chica`? where are they?

Comment: Hi @RokoC.Buljan I am finding my way around the site as this is my very first post and this space does not let me include code.

Comment: [edit] your Question, don't paste in comment.

Comment: start by looking at errors in browser console!! `lenght` is invalid property and certainly is one error

Comment: If you care about UX you should pause your gallery if the user is interested on the current slide and hovers it. 100% of *galleries in the wild* do that. Yours should also.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Loop and Pause on hover:

```js
var cur = 0, // Start Slide Index. We'll use ++cur to increment index
  pau = 2000,             // Pause Time (ms)
  fad = 500,              // Fade Time (ms)
  $ga = $('#gallery'),    // Cache Gallery Element
  $sl = $('> div', $ga),  // Cache Slides Elements
  tot = $sl.length,       // We'll use cur%tot to reset to first slide
  itv;                    // Used to clear on mouseenter

$sl.hide().eq(cur).show(); // Hide all Slides but desired one

function stop() { clearInterval(itv); }
function play() { itv = setInterval(anim, pau); }
function anim() { $sl.fadeOut(fad).eq(++cur % tot).stop().fadeIn(fad); }

$ga.hover(stop, play);
play(); // Play!
```

```css
/*QuickReset*/
*{margin:0;box-sizing:border-box;}html,body{height:100%;font:14px/1.4 sans-serif;}

/*Fade Gallery*/
#gallery {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
}
#gallery > div {
  position: absolute; /* overlap each slide */
  width: inherit;     /* as #gallery parent */
  height: inherit;    /* as #gallery parent */
  background: transparent none 50% 50% / cover no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div id="gallery">
  <div style="background-image:url('//placehold.it/960x310/0bf/fff')">
    Hover...
  </div>
  <div style="background-image:url('//placehold.it/960x310/f0b/fff')">
    ...to...
  </div>
  <div style="background-image:url('//placehold.it/960x310/b0f/fff')">
    ...pause!
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

---

If you want to use **CSS3 to accomplish the transitions** you can change the above to handle classes instead of the jQuery's animation methods:

```js
let cur = 0,
  itv = null;

const kls = "isVisible",
  $ga = $("#gallery"),
  $sl = $(">*", $ga),
  tot = $sl.length,
  stop = () => clearInterval(itv),
  play = () => itv = setInterval(anim, 2000),
  anim = () => {
    const $slCur = $sl.eq(cur);
    $sl.not($slCur).removeClass(kls);
    $slCur.addClass(kls);
    cur = ++cur % tot;
  };

$ga.hover(stop, play);
anim(); // Trigger current slide Visibility logic
play(); // Play!
```

```css
/*QuickReset*/
*{margin:0;box-sizing:border-box;}html,body{height:100%;font:14px/1.4 sans-serif;}

/*Fade Gallery*/
#gallery {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
}
#gallery > * {
  position: absolute; /* overlap each slide */
  width: inherit;     /* as #gallery parent */
  height: inherit;    /* as #gallery parent */
  background: transparent none 50% 50% / cover no-repeat;
  
  transition: 0.7s;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

#gallery > *.isVisible { /* this class is handled by JS */
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="gallery">
  <div style="background-image:url('//placehold.it/960x310/0bf/fff')">
    Hover...
  </div>
  <div style="background-image:url('//placehold.it/960x310/f0b/fff')">
    ...to...
  </div>
  <div style="background-image:url('//placehold.it/960x310/b0f/fff')">
    ...pause!
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi @Roko C. Buljan Thanks. I will try this but I have a question. Do I replace my current code complete with this or do I ADD this to current code?  Sorry am a real beginner at using Jquery.

Comment: @Agustin as you can see from my jsBin demo I used only my code and your HTML. Also you might want to set `position:relative;` `width` and `height` to the `#gallery` element. That's it. Place the jQuery code inside `<script></script>` tags before the closing `</body>` tag, put the css in place and you're good to go!

Comment: Thanks for that @Roko. Its almost there I just need to adjust the CSS to position the images in the right place but I seem to be missing still something on the jquery because as you can see in the implementation, before the next image appears it flashes right under the current image. I changed the page location to: "http://negociosensanjuan.com/w/Banquetes/" Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi @Roko Never mind the the previous comment. When I adjusted the css to position the images the above problem (The Flashing disappeared). I am looking now for the option to vote for your assistence!